# Values assignment in an array for loop

Tags: javascript

on this code from Flanagan's book:

```
var o = {x:1, y:4};
var keys = Object.keys(o);
var values = [];

console.log(keys); //[ 'x', 'y' ]

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  var key = keys[i];
  values[i] = o[key];
}

console.log(values); //[ 1, 4 ]
```

Why is there a need to first store keys[i] in a key variable, in order to access property VALUES of o on the line just after ? Why can't we just put values[i] = o[keys] (which returns undefined undefined) ?
"key" is an arbitrary variable name, I don't get the magic by which it establish a correspondance to o VALUES with o[key] ?

Comment: I think it is just for clarity. It could be `values[i] = o[keys[i]];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to extract a value from `o`, we need the values `1` and `4`, that values are stored in `keys` variable, so in order to extract those values we need to loop it starting from `0`, try view it step by step

Comment: 1 and 4 are values, x and y are keys.

Answer (score 0):

Keys is the array you need to get the key in keys to get the value,so the key is taken first and searched in keys array